undefined array keys in PHP
i'm trying to get information submitted from a table with rows that are dynamically added using javascript, i can't get my PHP working, i keep getting undefined array key errors.
I have tried changing the number that the loops start on and the numbers they stop on. The post data seems right, variables with increasing index numbers appended  on the end of the variable names.
My input names are alright, what am i missing because i can't see it?
Below is my code and my errors, HELP.
Collect post data from form
$jobName = $_POST['jobName'];
$jobNumber = $_POST['jobNumber'];
$jobDate = $_POST['jobDate'];
$coordinates = $_POST['coordinates'];
$customer = $_POST['customer'];
$operatives = $_POST['operatives'];
$rowCount = isset($_POST['rowCount']) ? intval($_POST['rowCount']) : 0;

//arrays
$markingTypes = [];
$colours = [];
$amounts = [];
$chkDrieds = [];
$txtComments = [];

// Loop through table adding the rows to the associated arrays
for ($t = 1; $t <= $rowCount; $t++) {
    $markingTypes[] = $_POST['markingType'][$t];
    $colours[] = $_POST['colour'][$t];
    $amounts[] = $_POST['amount'][$t];
    $chkDrieds[] = $_POST['chkDried'][$t];
    $txtComments[] = $_POST['txtComments'][$t];
}

I am getting "undefined array key" and "Trying to access array offset on value of type null for these lines:
$markingTypes[] = $_POST['markingType'][$t];
$colours[] = $_POST['colour'][$t];
$amounts[] = $_POST['amount'][$t];
$chkDrieds[] = $_POST['chkDried'][$t];
$txtComments[] = $_POST['txtComments'][$t];


Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots (how to format code in posts). Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

You're not creating array-style names in your form. You're doing markingType.name = "markingType" + index;. But the PHP code expects it to be markingType.name = "markingType[]"

Or change the PHP to use $_POST['markingType' . $t] instead of $_POST['markingType'][$t]`

PLEASE always supply ALL the error message, NEVER a summary like you have. You are missing the most important part of the error message

It looks like the POST data might be empty, which is causing the “undefined array key” and “trying to access array offset on value of type null” errors. If there’s a chance that the data can be empty, you should check for nullability and assign default values. If the data should never be empty, this might indicate a bug in the frontend, and it should be fixed to ensure that the correct data is always posted.
You can use the null coalescing operator ?? to provide a default value if the POST data is missing:
$markingTypes[] = $_POST['markingType'][$t] ?? 'default_marking_type';
$colours[] = $_POST['colour'][$t] ?? 'default_colour';
$amounts[] = $_POST['amount'][$t] ?? 0;
$chkDrieds[] = isset($_POST['chkDried'][$t]) ? $_POST['chkDried'][$t] : false;
$txtComments[] = $_POST['txtComments'][$t] ?? '';

Before the loop, you can use var_dump or print_r to inspect the POST data and see what’s being sent:
var_dump($_POST);
print_r($_POST);

This will help you understand what data is actually being received and whether any expected fields are missing or empty.
